# Is there a pop functionality for solidity arrays?

Tags: data-structures, solidity

I have used solidity to push data into an array. Is there a similar function for pop ?

```
string[] myArray;
myArray.push("hello")
```

What is the best solution for this ? How do I delete an element in a dynamic array in solidity ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Update 2-19-2019**: As Joel pointed out below, `pop` has been added to built-in array support. See https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.4/types.html#array-members. Leaving original answer on here in case others are using older versions of Solidity.

---

There is no pop function in Solidity. You have a few options you can consider for maintaining your array.

**Delete & Leave Gaps**

The simplest solution is to just `delete` the element at a specific index:

```
string element = myArray[index];
delete myArray[index];
return element;
```

However, this will NOT shift the elements in your array and will leave an element of "string 0" in your array. To check this element, you would use

`if(bytes(myArray[index]).length > 0) ...`

**Swap & Delete**

If you don't care about order in your array, you can swap the element with the last element in your array and then delete:

```
string element = myArray[index];
myArray[index] = myArray[myArray.length - 1];
delete myArray[myArray.length - 1];
myArray.length--;
return element;
```

**Delete With Shift**

If order in your array is important, you can delete the element then shift all remaining elements to the left.

```
string element = myArray[index];
for (uint i = index; i < myArray.length - 1; i++) {
  myArray[i] = myArray[i + 1];
}
delete myArray[myArray.length - 1];
myArray.length--;
return element;
```

Note that this will be the most expensive of the options. If your array is very long, you will have high gas usage.

Correlating with @Jedsada's suggestion, here is a version as a library:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

library StackLib {
  using StackLib for Stack;

  struct Stack {
    uint[] _items;
  }

  function pushElement(Stack storage self, uint element) internal returns (bool) {
    self._items.push(element);
  }

  function popElement(Stack storage self) internal returns (uint) {
    uint element = self.peek();

    if (self.size() > 0)
      delete self._items[self.size() - 1];

    return element;
  }

  function peek(Stack storage self) internal returns (uint) {
    uint value;

    if (self.size() > 0)
      value = self._items[self.size() - 1];

    return value;
  }

  function size(Stack storage self) internal returns (uint8) {
    return self.size();
  }
}
```

Example usage (Important note: You can't use `popElement` and return the value to a client. That method changes state and should only be used within a transaction.):

```
contract Test {
  using StackLib for StackLib.Stack;

  StackLib.Stack numbers;

  function add(uint v) public {
    numbers.pushElement(v);
  }

  function doSomething() public {
    for (uint8 i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
      uint curNum = numbers.popElement();

      // do something with curNum
    }
  }
}
```

Additional note: Unfortunately, `var` has been deprecated since 0.4.20 and there is no replacement for generics. You have to customize for a specific type.

Comment: Okay.. this makes sense.. and that is why in solidity I can actually go ahead and change the length of the dynamic array.. unlike other languages, where it's a function.

Comment: Thanks - very helpful explanation. I think there's a minor mistake in the `Swap & Delete` example though. `delete[myArray.length - 1];` should actually be `delete myArray[myArray.length - 1];`, no?

Comment: Im getting error `TypeError: Member "length" is read-only and cannot be used to resize arrays.`

Comment: @Codler - length was made read only in 0.6. From release notes “Member-access to length of arrays is now always read-only, even for storage arrays. It is no longer possible to resize storage arrays by assigning a new value to their length. Use push(), push(value) or pop() instead, or assign a full array, which will of course overwrite the existing content. The reason behind this is to prevent storage collisions of gigantic storage arrays.”

Answer (score 2):

**You can try...**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract TestArray {
   uint[] public items;

   constructor () public {
      items.push(1);
      items.push(2);
      items.push(3);
      items.push(4);
   }

   function pushElement(uint value) public {
      items.push(value);
   }

   function popElement() public returns (uint []){
      delete items[items.length-1];
      items.length--;
      return items;
   }

   function getArrayLength() public view returns (uint) {
      return items.length;
   }

   function getFirstElement() public view returns (uint) {
      return items[0];
   }

   function getAllElement()  public view returns (uint[]) {
      return items;
   }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend to write this as a library, though.

Comment: @L. Guthardt Sorry! I busy

Comment: @AdamKipnis i create utils for list integer, integer and string but i research for use type dynamic array in solidity but i not found. you can join for creating other utils.

https://github.com/20Scoops-CNX/solidity-utils

Comment: @JedsadaTiwongvorakul See my updated answer for an example.

Comment: function getAllElement()  public view returns (uint[] memory) {
        return numbers;
    }

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is, as of v0.5.0 ([details here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.5.4/types.html#array-members)):

> Dynamic storage arrays and bytes (not string) have a member function called pop that you can use to remove an element from the end of the array. This also implicitly calls :ref:delete on the removed element.

Answer (score 1):

```
function deleteElement(uint _index) public returns(bool) {
    if (_index < 0 || _index >= x.length) {
        return false;
    } else if(x.length == 1) {
        x.pop();
        return true;
    } else if (_index == x.length - 1) {
        x.pop();
        return true;
    } else {
        for (uint i = _index; i < x.length - 1; i++) {
            x[i] = x[i + 1];
        }
        
        x.pop();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add more details about you code and how does it answers the question.