# Remove an element in array but the struct is still inside

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I have this array of struct

```
struct Prodotto {
    string titolo;
    address owner_address;
}

Prodotto[] public prodotti;
```

And I create two products like this:

```
titolo: titolo stravolto
owner: 0x144c9617C69B52547f7c2c526352E137488FAF0c

titolo: titolo secondo prodotto
owner: 0xa53709839ab6Da3ad9c1518Ed39a4a0fFCbA3684
```

I want to delete the element with index 0

in my contract I have this function

```
function deleteProdotto(uint _id_prodotto) external payable onlyOwnerOf(_id_prodotto) {
  delete prodotti[0];    
}
```

If I retrive element to index 0, I have a product like this

```
titolo:
owner: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

How can I delete that index?
I know that after that I have to do

```
prodotti.length--
```

But before I have to resolve this issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a pop functionality for solidity arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49051856/is-there-a-pop-functionality-for-solidity-arrays)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to move every element after that so that you don't leave a "gap". There is not a way to delete and rearrange the elements unless you do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
contract test {
    struct Prodotto {
        string titolo;
        address owner_address;
    }
    Prodotto[] public prodotti;

    constructor() public {
        for (uint i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            prodotti.push(Prodotto({
                titolo: 'one more',
                owner_address: address(i)
            }));
        }
    }

    function remove(uint index) public {
        for (uint i = index; i < prodotti.length-1; i++) {
            prodotti[i] = prodotti[i+1];
        }
        delete prodotti[prodotti.length-1];
        prodotti.length--;
    }

    function check() public view returns(uint256) { return prodotti.length; }
}
```

Comment: This seems highly inefficient. In some cases, it could be necessary, but if you do not care about the order, you can just move the last one only.